# Javascript - remove empty or false items from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm decoding a file using php on the server. When the response is served to the client and I'm using the `v-if` to loop it in my vue app I'm encountering a strange beahviour, it will loop all the items correctly and they are displayed on the screen (I'm looping images in data uri format) but inside the loop I will always get two `false` items so on the output I will have two blank image tags. I'm not sure if this is caused from the looped data URI but is there any way to remove the false items from the array?

This is the client code

```
      axios.request({
        url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/readfile', 
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.$store.getters.userToken}`
        },
        data: formData
      }).then( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        response.data.master_file.forEach( (item) => {
          console.log(item);
          this.payload.push(item);
        });
        this.step++;
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you tried anything?

Comment: Just wrap `this.payload.push(item)` inside an if statement and check if item exists

Comment: @ozgur nice solution, I didn't thought about it. Can I use also a ternary operator to check for the items?

Comment: @newbiedev I will post it as an answer so you can try

Comment: Thank you, it will be useful for all people with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `Array.push()` in an if statement to avoid adding `false` items.

```
axios.request({
url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/readfile', 
method: 'GET',
headers: {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.$store.getters.userToken}`
},
data: formData
}).then( (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    response.data.master_file.forEach( (item) => {
      console.log(item);
      if (item) {
        this.payload.push(item);
      }
    });
    this.step++;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```